# Headerfile is not properly included

Tags: c, operating-system

A Header file(stdint.h) is not included. I know a lot of code is following, but I have really no idea.

My Files:

gdt.c

```
/* We need 8 segments */
#include <stdint.h>
#include "gdt.h"
#define GDT_SIZE 8
uint32_t intr;

gdt_entry gdtable[GDT_SIZE];
```

include/gdt.h

```
#ifndef GDT_H
#define GDT_H
#include <stdint.h>
struct gdt_entry{
    uint_16t limit;
    uint_32t base :24;
    uint_32t accessbyte :8;
    uint_32t limit2 :4;
    uint_32t flags2 :4;
    uint_32t base2 :8;
}__attribute__((packed));
#endif
```

include/stdint.h

```
#ifndef STDINT_H
#define STDINT_H

typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

typedef signed long long int64_t;
typedef signed int int32_t;
typedef signed short int16_t;
typedef signed char int8_t;

#endif
```

Makefile:

```
SRCS = $(shell find -name '*.[cS]')
OBJS = $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRCS)))

CC = gcc
LD = ld

ASFLAGS = -m32
CFLAGS = -m32 -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector -I include
LDFLAGS = -melf_i386 -Tkernel.ld

kernel: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

%.o: %.S
    $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm $(OBJS)

.PHONY: clean
```

kernel.ld

```
/*  start should be executed first */
ENTRY(_start)

/*
 * thats how the sections should be written in the .elf binary
 */
SECTIONS
{
    /*
     * the first section has a 1MB Offset for the grub bootloader
     */
    . = 0x100000;

     /*
      * the multiboot header comes first
      */
     .text : {
         *(multiboot)
         *(.text)
     }
     .data ALIGN(4096) : {
         *(.data)
     }
     .rodata ALIGN(4096) : {
         *(.rodata)
     }
     .bss ALIGN(4096) : {
         *(.bss)
     }
}
```

gcc output:

```
gcc -m32 -c -o start.o start.S
gcc -m32 -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector -I include -c -o gdt.o gdt.c
In file included from gdt.c:3:0:
include/gdt.h:5:2: error: unknown type name ‘uint_16t’
include/gdt.h:6:2: error: unknown type name ‘uint_32t’
include/gdt.h:7:2: error: unknown type name ‘uint_32t’
include/gdt.h:8:2: error: unknown type name ‘uint_32t’
include/gdt.h:9:2: error: unknown type name ‘uint_32t’
include/gdt.h:10:2: error: unknown type name ‘uint_32t’
gdt.c:7:1: error: unknown type name ‘gdt_entry’
make: *** [gdt.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `uint32_t` instead of the non-standard `uint_32t`. It's at least the third variant I've come across, previously I've also seen `u_int32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

There was another issue:
gdt_entry gdtable[GDT_SIZE]; should be struct gdt_entry gdtable[GDT_SIZE]